# Accessing a variable in another scene

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to change a variable in another scene in unity. I have a script right now that has the user pick 5 heroes and those 5 heroes get saved to a array, but in order for the game to run how i want it, that array will be in another scene and I'm not sure how to go about saving the five heroes data to an array in another scene. I can do it all in one scene but 2 scenes would be more efficient. Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

 public class HeroChooser : MonoBehaviour {
public static GameObject Archer;
 GameObject Berserker;
 GameObject Rouge;
 GameObject Warrior;
 GameObject Mage;
 GameObject MainCamera;
 public int counter = 0;
 public bool archerOn = false;
 public bool berserkerOn = false;
 public bool rougeOn = false;
 public bool mageOn = false;
 public bool warriorOn = false;





// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
void OnGUI(){
    if(archerOn == false){
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect(50,0,50,50), "Archer")){
        Archer = GameObject.Find("Archer");
        MainCamera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
        HeroArraySaver heroArraySaver =     MainCamera.GetComponent<HeroArraySaver>();
        heroArraySaver.array[counter] = Archer;
        archerOn = true;
        counter++;


    }
    }
```

Its saying that: Static member `HeroArraySaver.array` cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead im not sure how to go about fixing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way would be to create an empty GameObject and attach a script/MonoBehaviour to that which holds your data. To make it persist you would have to call [DontDestroyOnLoad()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) on that GameObject. This will ensure your GameObject will hang around when moving to a different scene.

So something like:

```c#
GameObject myPersistentDataObject = new GameObject("myPersistentDataObject");
MyDataClass data_class = myPersistentDataObject.AddComponent<MyDataClass>();
//set your data to whatever you need to maintain
```

And in your Awake of your MyDataClass you'd do something like

```c#
void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
}
```

Then in your other scene you can simply find your GameObject again and retrieve its data from the attached component.

Comment: Thanks for the response ill used this thanks! But how would i go about accessing and changing variables in another scene?

Comment: Just find your GameObject (by name possibly) and use GetComponent to retrieve your data component. Then you can modify it as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have integer IDs for the heroes, simply store them in a static variable:

```cs
public class GlobalData {
    public static int[] heroIds;
}
```

Static variables can be accessed from any scene and will persist as long as your game runs. The same technique works for strings or enums.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I changed my array to a static array but found that in my other script that gives the array variables values unity is saying:  Static member `HeroArraySaver.array' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: You didn't show the code for your `HeroArraySaver` class and in the code you posted, you wrote `heroArraySaver.array` with a lowercase `h`, not `HeroArraySaver.array`. You should use the latter. Also note that if you store `GameObject`s in that array, you also have to call `DontDestroyOnLoad` like described in the other answer.